# Trouble in Java TimerTask Interval

Tags: java, android, timer

Sorry for my bad english.

I'm implementing Java TimerTask when creating an Android application. The code isn't to complicated. When it hit the interval, it will send an SMS & email.

I have some option with the sending SMS / email interval. 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, and 2 hour.

I tried using 5 minutes, and 15 minutes (I converted it into milis), no trouble occurred. It send sms and email every 5 / 15 minutes exactly. And I prove that i have no problem using timertask.

But, when I changed it to 30 minutes or more. my application cannot send sms / email. It looked like that the timer didn't work correctly.

Does it have any interval limitation on using Timer Task ??

this is my code snippet.

```
private void activateNotificationByInterval(int notificationInterval) {
    timerNotificationByInterval = new Timer();
    timerNotificationByInterval.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // coba
            // if (oldLatitude != childLatitude
            // && oldLongitude != childLongitude) {
            if ((enableSMS == true)) {
                sendSMS();
            }

            if ((enableEmail == true)) {
                GMailSender email = new GMailSender(sender, senderPassword);
                try {
                    email.sendMail(emailSubject + childsName, SMSMessage
                            + " " + childlLocation + "\nLatitude: "
                            + childLatitude + "\nLongitude: "
                            + childLongitude, sender, destination);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mpv.changeLastLocation(childLatitude, childLongitude);
            // buat method untuk menangkap lokasi pertama
            oldLatitude = childLatitude;
            oldLongitude = childLongitude;
            // } else {
            // System.out.println("Lokasi Lama Berpengaruh");
            // }

        }
    }, 0, notificationInterval);
}
```

*notes : notificationInterval on milis (*60000)

can you tell me how to solved it ? thank you.

Comment: TimerTask get killed after some time and do not work properly on some devices. you should go for AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try AlarmManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AlarmManager and there is a link here:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html